# Suggestions on a Ubuntu version suitable for this machine:

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a 6/7 year old Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop which came with:
1GB DDR RAM,
120GB HDD,
(Dual core?) AMD Turion Processor,
Windows Vista Home Premium which now boots extremely slowly.

I'd prefer to replace it with a light/full version of Ubuntu which runs fairly well. Any suggestions on which version of Ubuntu to install on it, and any GUI options (Kubuntu/Lubuntu) which would make it perform faster.

I would like to mention that I do use Scientific Linux and Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 on a daily basis, but I have no knowledge of past versions and how well they would run on slower laptops.

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: This is too broad and opinion based.  As well, we've answered this question multiple times on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found Xubuntu to be the fastest of the buntu distros on my dell mini 10v.

Answer (score 0):

Try a live CD version first. It will give you some idea of the performance.